# problems on prime factorization program in c. It doesnt work always. It only works in some cases

Tags: c

The purpose of this program is to break down any prime numbers from any given number.

It works fine except for some cases. For example it doesn't work with the number 1024. I don't understand what's the problem. I would really appreciate your help.. thanks in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n1,n0,A[100];
    char i,j,p=0;
    printf("insert number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    n0=n1;
    for(i=2; i<=n1; i++)
    {

        while (n0%i==0)
        {
            n0=n0/i;
            A[p]=i;
            p++;

        }
    }
    for(j=0; j<p; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",A[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Is there an error output you can provide or an expected/actual output?

Comment: simply there is no output in some cases and the program never finishes

Comment: Mark Tolonen is right, and it looks like the code would work correctly with that fix. But consider, if `n1 == 1024`, do you really need to check all the possible divisors up to 1024? What if you were trying to factor `2 ** 30`? Your algorithm would run very slowly. Think about possible improvements.

Comment: now thanks to mark tolonen advice it work perfectly. Thank you all!

Comment: Tom Zych you're right, surely there are far better algorithmes than this but i'm at very basic level..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is using `char i`.  The range of (signed) char on most systems is -128 to 127.

`i` will never reach `n1` if it is greater than 127.  Use `int` instead.